# Does Locktopus 1.1 work on iOS 4.3.1?

Tags: iphone, applications, jailbreak

I want to upgrade to 4.3.1 but wonder whether Locktopus 1.1 still works ... thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Yes it does work. I have personally tried it. So, go ahead.